# Unable to access/modify desired pointer value after calling a library function

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

I'm using an external library https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/jacobi_eigenvalue/jacobi_eigenvalue.c to calculate eigenvalue of a matrix. However, after calling the library function, I received Segmentation fault when I tried to access desired pointer values.

```
void asphericity(particle *p, int N, float aveLTail[MAX2][MAX2], double *Nominator, double *Denominator, double *Asp ,double *cmx, double *cmy, double *cmz){
int i, j, k,m,n,M;
double x[10000];
double y[10000];
double z[10000];
double *Q;
double gyration[3][3];
double v[M*M];
double d[M];
float ut, up;
float bs;
double hdistance;
double tdistance;
double rog; 
int hcount=0;
int tcount=0;
int it_max;
int it_num;
int rot_num;
double hx=0;
double hy=0;
double hz=0;
double tx=0;
double ty=0;
double tz=0;
m=0;


it_max=100;
for(i = 1; i<=N; i++) {
   if (p[i].mol == p[i-1].mol){
       if (p[i-1].type==1 ||p[i-1].type==2 || p[i-1].type==3 || p[i-1].type==6){
            hcount++;
            hx += p[i-1].x;
            hy += p[i-1].y;
            hz += p[i-1].z;
       }
       else if (p[i-1].type==4 && p[i-2].type==9){
            tcount++;
            tx += p[i-1].x;
            ty += p[i-1].y;
            tz += p[i-1].z;
            hcount += 2;
            hx += p[i-2].x+p[i-3].x;
            hy += p[i-2].y+p[i-3].y;
            hz += p[i-2].z+p[i-3].z;
        }  
       else if (p[i-1].type==4 && p[i-2].type!=9){
            tcount++;
            tx += p[i-1].x;
            ty += p[i-1].y;
            tz += p[i-1].z;
       }

   }
   else if (p[i].mol != p[i-1].mol && p[i-1].mol!=0) {
            tcount++;
            tx += p[i-1].x;
            ty += p[i-1].y;
            tz += p[i-1].z;
           (hx) /= hcount; /*geometric center of head beads*/
           (hy) /= hcount;
           (hz) /= hcount;
           (tx) /= tcount;
           (ty) /= tcount;
           (tz) /= tcount;
           hcount=0;
           tcount=0;
           hdistance=sqrt(pow((hx-*cmx),2)+pow((hy-*cmy),2)+pow((hz-*cmz),2));
           tdistance=sqrt(pow((tx-*cmx),2)+pow((ty-*cmy),2)+pow((tz-*cmz),2));
           if(hdistance>tdistance){
              x[m]=hx;
              y[m]=hy;
              z[m]=hz;
              m++;
             }
           hx=0;
           hy=0;
           hz=0;
           tx=0;
           ty=0;
           tz=0;
         }              
   } 


for(j = 0; j<m; j++) {
    gyration[0][0]+= pow((x[j]-*cmx),2);
    gyration[0][1]+=(x[j]-*cmx)*(y[j]-*cmy);
    gyration[0][2]+=(x[j]-*cmx)*(z[j]-*cmz); 
    gyration[1][0]+=(y[j]-*cmy)*(x[j]-*cmx);
    gyration[1][1]+=pow((y[j]-*cmy),2);
    gyration[1][2]+=(y[j]-*cmy)*(z[j]-*cmz);
    gyration[2][0]+=(z[j]-*cmz)*(x[j]-*cmx);
    gyration[2][1]+=(z[j]-*cmz)*(y[j]-*cmy);
    gyration[2][2]+=pow((z[j]-*cmz),2);
 }
for(i =0; i<3; i++){
   for(j=0; j<3; j++){
       gyration[i][j]/=m;
      }
}

 #define M 3
double Gyration[M*M] = { 
          gyration[0][0],gyration[0][1],gyration[0][2], 
          gyration[1][0],gyration[1][1],gyration[1][2],
          gyration[2][0],gyration[2][1],gyration[2][2] };
printf("%.6f\t%.6f\t%.6f\n", *Denominator, *Nominator, *Asp);
jacobi_eigenvalue(M, Gyration, it_max, v, d, &it_num, &rot_num);
printf("%.6f\t%.6f\t%.6f\n", *Denominator, *Nominator, *Asp);
rog = sqrt(d[0]+d[1]+d[2]);  
*Denominator= 2*pow(rog,4); 
*Nominator= pow((d[2]-d[1]),2)+pow((d[2]-d[0]),2)+pow((d[1]-d[0]),2);
* Asp = (*Nominator)/(*Denominator);
# undef M
 }
```

**Denominator, Nominator, and Asp** were defined as double variables in main function and passed as pointers. However I received segmentation fault when I was trying to access them after library function call. I was able to access the output v[] and d[].

The first printf shows *Denominator, *Nominator and *Asp zero while the segmentation fault appears at second printf.  So, something is not correct in the library function.  But, I am not sure where exactly the issue is and how to fix it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does debugging line by line and inspecting variables reveal?

Comment: Could you share complete program code? Or at least reduced one, but that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I was able to access *Denominator, *Nominator, and *Asp( which are all 0) before the library function call. (checked using gdb)  However, I got sigsegv segmentation fault message at  *Denominator= 2*pow(rog,4). I am unable to access memory of this variable. So I think something messed up in library function.

Comment: anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: I already added the entire function code.

Comment: I see `int M` defined at the top and two arrays allocated using its value which is not assigned, but macro M is defined later in the code and its value is set to 3.

Answer (score 0):

A summary view of your code reveals several potential "divide by zero" errors. Focusing on *Denominator, the following is a potential pitfall:

```
* Asp = (*Nominator)/(*Denominator);
```

If *Denominator is zero, then you will crash (divide by zero). Also, you have this in a for loop:

```
int hcount=0;

// some code

if (p[i].mol == p[i-1].mol){ 

  if (p[i-1].type==1 ||p[i-1].type==2 || p[i-1].type==3 || p[i-1].type==6){

     hcount++; 

  }
  else {
     // hcount incremented
  }
  // some code
}
else if (p[i].mol != p[i-1].mol && p[i-1].mol!=0) {
        tcount++;
        tx += p[i-1].x;
        ty += p[i-1].y;
        tz += p[i-1].z;
       (hx) /= hcount; /*geometric center of head beads*/
       (hy) /= hcount;
       (hz) /= hcount;
       (tx) /= tcount;
       (ty) /= tcount;
       (tz) /= tcount;
  }
```

Notice that in the else, you divide by hcount; hcount is initialised to zero at declaration and is only incremented in the first if statement within the for loop; if that first iteration does not satisfy that first if condition and finds its way in the else, then you will divide by zero.

Also, no need for

```
p[i].mol != p[i-1].mol
```

in

```
else if (p[i].mol != p[i-1].mol && p[i-1].mol!=0)
```

because it necessarily follows if the first if condition fails.